# Alternate expression for finite summation

Tags: sequences-and-series, numerical-methods, summation

"How many arithmetic operations are required to directly compute
$$y=1+x+x^2+...+x^{1023}$$
Use a formula for the sum to come up with an alternate expression for $y$, and show that only 10 multiplications are now required."

Workings so far:
I determined that the number of multiplications would be 1024 (using nested evaluations) and that the number of additions would also be 1024. I re-wrote $y$ as $$y=\sum_{n=0}^{1023}{x^n}$$ But I do not understand how to show that only 10 multiplications are required.

Any help or insight would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you know the formula for the sum of a finite geometric series? For this is a geometric series with ratio $x$.

Comment: Do you mean $\sum_{n=0}^{1023}=\frac{1-x^{1024}}{1-x}$? How can that make it so only 10 multiplications are required?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint $1$:** Multiply your sum with $1-x$, and see what happens. :-)

**Hint $2$:** $1024=2^{10}$, $a^b\cdot a^c=a^{b+c}$, and $2^n+2^n=2\cdot2^n=2^{n+1}$.

Comment: Awesome, figured it out thanks to your hints!